# Windows 7 explorer DPI smaller than 100%

Tags: windows-7, dpi

First I had Windows 7 indicate my default DPI is medium at 125%, it made all my programs run at 125% zoomed. If I changed the DPI to 100%, then everything except explorer.exe runs at 100%.

At 100%, the context menu, window title bars, command buttons among others all appear to be smaller than 100%. Anyone knows what is wrong and how to fix it?

[image: example of title bar text becoming smaller than 100%]

Example of title bar text becoming smaller, but the rest stay at 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to accidentally fix it.

What I did was go into regedit and find every instance of the key "LogPixels" and change the value to 96 decimal, which stands for 96 dpi, the 100% value.

Log out and log in. At this point, it may be the case that not all the dpi has changed.

Then go back to the Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display set the dpi to medium.

log out and log in again. I change the dpi from the Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display more than once, each time logging out and in again. On the 7th or 8th try the dpi went back to normal.

Comment: You mention logging out and back in.  Did you try just restarting the computer?

Comment: @afrazier no i did not restart the computer because changing it in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display only instruct me to re logon to the profile. Maybe, yea, I could have worked too.

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to, but troubleshooting step #1 is always "restart Windows" :-)